# file not including in wordpress header

Tags: php, include, include-path, file-inclusion

i want to include a file in the header file which is in this directory :

> **wp-content/themes/themename/header.php**

the code i used for inclusion is :

```
include("../../plugins/booking/informationform.php");
```

while the file which i want to include is in this directory :

> **wp-content/plugins/booking/informationform.php**

so this gives me an error like this :

> Warning: include(../../plugins/booking/informationform.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/zapptv/domains/tvworkshop.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/tvworkshop/header.php
>   on line 100
>
> Warning: include(../../plugins/booking/informationform.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in
>   /home/zapptv/domains/tvworkshop.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/tvworkshop/header.php
>   on line 100
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '../../plugins/booking/informationform.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/zapptv/domains/tvworkshop.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/tvworkshop/header.php
>   on line 100

but when i copy the file in the same directory where the header is and include it with filename only then it s not giving any error and including successfully.

Comment: Why do you need a relative path? There are functions in Wordpress you can use to work out what the correct path is, and it will take care of figuring out where the file is for you.

Comment: can you please briefly answer what to do with it, my aim is to include the file, no matter which way :)

Comment: Here you go: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path